# How to add search functionality of static pages to Ruby on Rails app without a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, indexing

Anyone know of any good gems or documentation on how to index static pages within a rails app to add search functionality? So far my search has led me to [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/) and [Cobweb](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/cobweb), but both seem to be a little more complicated than what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's an example of how my views directory looks:

```
views
|
|__Folder_1
   |
   |__ View-1
   |__ View-2
   |
   Folder_2
   |
   |__ View-3
   |__ View-4
```

Each folder is a controller with the views as defined actions if that makes any difference when considering how to set this up. The end goal is to return a list of links for pages that include the searched terms.

**Edit:**

Each search query is intended to crawl through the HTML contents of all static pages and return a list of links for pages that match any non stop word term searched. I also plan on adding relevancy to the search based on the frequency of the searched terms within a static page and word placement.

Example:

Search Query: "Recipe for scrambled eggs"
- Would return a link for any page with the words "recipe", "scrambled", and "eggs" with the most relevant links placed at the top of the returned list:

```
Search Results:
Page 1 (Most relevant because includes all 3 terms)
Page 2 (Includes 2 terms)
Page 3 (Includes 1 terms)
```

Preferably, the search functionality would only attempt to match searched terms to the text of each view so that if a user entered 'div' as a search term it would not return every single page because div elements exist within the HTML content.

**Answer:**

After a few weeks of studying Ruby this is what I've come up with - Basically I'm filtering through each sub directory within my /app/views/ directory, reading each file within the sub directory's contents, processing the text to remove HTML tags and common stop words, and storing it within a search index hash.

search_controller.rb

```
#include sanitize helper to enable use of strip_tags method in controller
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

class SearchController < ApplicationController

  prepend_before_filter :search

  def search
    if params[:q]
      stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "aren't", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "can't", "cannot", "could", "couldn't", "did", "didn't", "do", "does", "doesn't", "doing", "don't", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "hadn't", "has", "hasn't", "have", "haven't", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "isn't", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "mustn't", "my", "myself", "no", "nor", "not", "of", "off", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "shan't", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "shouldn't", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "wasn't", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "weren't", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "won't", "would", "wouldn't", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself"]
      #cleanse all stop words from search query
      @search_terms = strip_tags(params[:q]).downcase.split.delete_if{|x| stopwords.include?(x)}

      #declare empty index hash
      @search_index = {}

      #filter through each view and add view text to search entry
      Rails.root.join('app', "views").entries.each do |view_dir| 
        unless %w(. .. search shared layouts).include?(view_dir.to_s) 
          Rails.root.join('app', "views", view_dir.to_s).entries.each do |view| 
            unless %w(. ..).include?(view.to_s)
              #add relative path for view and processed contents to search index hash as key, value pair
              @search_index["/" + view_dir.to_s + "/" + view.to_s.gsub('.html.erb', '')] = strip_tags(IO.read(Rails.root.join('app', "views", view_dir.to_s, view.to_s))).downcase.squish.split.delete_if{|x| stopwords.include?(x)}.join(" ")
            end
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end

end
```

If anyone has any improvements or suggestions I would love to hear them!

Comment: As with any search feature, you have documents which can be matched by entering search queries. The thing is, what do you want those queries to match to? View file names? View HTML contents? Your question would be improved by some examples of search queries and the views that match them (and why they match).

Comment: I think the difficult part of your problem is to list all these directories in your page, you have that already?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - Just updated my question with a better description of what I'm looking to implement. @juanpastas not sure if this is what you mean, but yes my app (specifically views dir) is already set up with 5 folders/controllers with 22 static pages/actions.

Comment: If you are willing to write some code, I believe it can be done. I'm not going to write out the full answer. I would set up a config that points to all static pages and has metadata for them (anchors without text are pretty useless to human beings). I would use `whistlepig` to build an in-memory search index over your static views in an initializer. I would use `nokogiri` to do HTML sanitizing. I would use the index to serve search results. Note that `whistlepig` has no ranking so to get that you'd have to do even more work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a predefined list of search terms and the views they match, you could implement a limited version of your static page search functionality with a hard-coded term index:

```
# app/controllers/searches_controller.rb
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    query = params[:query]

    # Convert query string to lowercase tokens, e.g. 
    # /search?query=cAT+aNd+doG => ['cat', 'and', 'dog']
    terms = query.downcase.split

    # Match each search term against the index, collecting all matching pages.
    @pages = terms.collect do |term|
      get_search_index[term]
    end

    # Remove nil objects resulting from terms not matching anything.
    @pages.compact!

    # Flatten all nested arrays into one array of pages for easy looping.
    @pages.flatten!
  end

  private
    def get_search_index
      @@index ||= {
        "homepage" => [
          {:path => root_path, :name => "Home"}
        ],
        "home" => [
          {:path => root_path, :name => "Home"}
        ],
        "user" => [
          {:path => new_user_path, :name => "Create New User"}, 
          {:path => users_path, :name => "User Index"}
        ]
      }
    end
end
```

Now for the view:

```
# app/views/searches/index.html.erb
Search results:
<ol>
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <li><%= link_to page[:name], page[:path] %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

Now you can go to `/searches?query=some+User+page` and the new user form and user index page should both show up in the search results (because the "User" term matched).

You can extend this static approach to get more fancy, too. For example, instead of hardcoding terms you could actually take an example body of text from the static page and split that into terms. For instance:

```
# Get a corpus, lowercase it, replace punctuation with whitespace, and tokenize.
@@homepage_terms = "Block of homepage text.".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]/, ' ').split
@@about_page_terms = "Block of about page text.".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]/, ' ').split

def get_search_index
  # Memoize the index so we only build it once.
  @@index ||= build_search_index
end

def build_search_index
  index = {}
  @@homepage_terms.each do |term|
    index[term] ||= []
    index[term] << {path: root_path, name: "Home"}
  end
  @@about_page_terms.each do |term|
    index[term] ||= []
    index[term] << {path: root_path, name: "About page"}
  end
  index
end
```

Your `build_search_index` function can get as complex and feature rich as you want. Essentially what you are doing is reinventing the wheel. Solr and other search backends were built to do this kind of work for you. I leave doing rankings, reading view files from disk, and HTML sanitization as an exercise for the reader :)

If you want something more dynamic, i.e. something that adjusts automatically as your pages change, it will look similar except that hash will be generated by scanning the views folder. Dynamic approaches are much more complicated, though. For one, where do you get the human-readable page titles for your search results? That metadata isn't contained anywhere in Rails. Also, how do you know which pages are GET pages? And what if you have secure pages or pages you don't want to appear in search results? Plus you'd have to interpret ERB. It's not impossible to render your static views server-side but what if these pages vary per user? And what about internationalization?

A manually-curated solution like the one I give above seems like the best option to me. If your site is like most, your static pages won't change much, so maintenance shouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I should also let you know this is my first solo attempt at a rails app other than completing Michael Hartl's tutorial, so I'm a little confused on how your answer works. That being said I definitely don't expect you (or anyone) to attempt to explain the basics or write out a full solution, but if you could point me in the direction of any tutorials or docs that would be very helpful :). Lastly, my site is a documentation site and will not vary per user or even have a structure for users. The app simply serves up the static pages, which will be updated over time.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding it, I suggest running it. Let me know if you have any issues or questions. I don't mind helping out with the basics.